# unable to read properties using configurationproperties annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        GlobalProperties globalProperties = context.getBean(GlobalProperties.class);
        System.out.println(globalProperties);
    }
}

@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:global.yml")
@ConfigurationProperties("app")
public class GlobalProperties {

    private String error;
    private List<Menu> menus = new ArrayList<>();
    private Compiler compiler = new Compiler();

    public static class Menu {
        private String name;
        private String path;
        private String title;

    //getters and setters and tostring

    }

    public static class Compiler {
        private String timeout;
        private String outputFolder;

    //getters and setters and tostring
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "GlobalProperties [error=" + error + ", menus=" + menus + ", compiler=" + compiler + "]";
    }


}
```

global.yml file in src/main/resources folder

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.web: ERROR
    com.mkyong: DEBUG
email: test@mkyong.com
thread-pool: 10
app:
  menus:
    - title: Home
      name: Home
      path: /
    - title: Login
      name: Login
      path: /login
  compiler:
    timeout: 5
    output-folder: /temp/
  error: /error/
```

When i run the application i am not seeing the global.yml properties being read correctly. i am getting this as o/p

```
GlobalProperties [error=null, menus=[], compiler=Compiler{timeout='null', outputFolder='null'}]
```

Did i miss anything in the above code to read the properties from the yml file.
I also tried replacing global.yml with global.properties and that didn't work too.

Comment: Use @Configuration instead of Component annotation in your GlobalProperties ...Let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add setters to your GlobalProperties class, like you do for nested static classes.

Comment: Added the getters and setters, other thing i had to do is to move everything in global.yml file to application.yml to get it to work. @propertysource is not working, tried propertysource with both yml and .properties file. Any reason for propertysource not working?

Comment: propertysource worked for .properties file, but i also need to have component annotation. without component annotation, propertysource is not working with enableconfigurationsource annotation

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, a spring `@component` class with local variables needs to have setters (and getters as well will be a good practice) for those variables. spring uses a no-args constructor to manufacture beans and components, and utilizes setters to initialize variables. 
This of course is also true for `@component` 3 sub-types: `@service`, `@repository` and `@controller`.

Also make sure to explicitly write a no-args constructor, if you're adding any other constructor (which will over-ride the 'invisible' no-args constructor that exists by default)