# Unable to retrieve value from Properties file using Spring's @Value, @ConfigurationProperties annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

I am new to Spring Boot and using Spring Annotations. I am trying to build a sample spring boot application in which I get a value for my java property using the properties file. I am trying to use `@Component` & `@ConfigurationProperties` parameter. I followed a bunch of tutorials online and this [StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51469609/unable-to-read-properties-using-configurationproperties-annotation) helped, but my property value is still `null`

Here is my code.

Looked through:-

1. [unable to read properties using configurationproperties annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51469609/unable-to-read-properties-using-configurationproperties-annotation)
2. https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertysources-example/

My SpringBoot Application class

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context =   SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    TestConf t = context.getBean(TestConf.class);
    System.out.println(t.toString());
  }
}
```

TestConf Class

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("pres")
public class TestConf {

  private String firstName;

  public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
  }

  public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
  }

  public TestConf()
  {
    System.out.println("inside constructor");
    System.out.println("first name:" + firstName);
  }


  public static void main(String[] args){
    TestConf t = new TestConf();
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "firstName:" + firstName;
  }
}
```

application.properties

```
pres.firstName=JACQUELYN
```

lastly my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>phil</groupId>
  <artifactId>springTuit</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Optional, for bootstrap -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
      <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <!-- Package as an executable jar/war -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.0</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

What is missing to retrieve the value from `application.properties` correctly into firstName?
Does it matter where my `application.properties` file lies? Although it is in its traditional spot under `src/main/resources` and my java files are under `src/main/java`

Comment: You have to specify where it is located since you are moving to default location . Spring boot always look for properties file under resources folder . to change you can use this property `--spring.config.location="file:/path/to/application.properties"`

Comment: If you check, `firstName` would only be `null` on the constructor of `TestConf` and printing fine on the `main` method in `Main` class

Comment: Also, why do you have a `main` method in the `TestConf` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems standard. However, you can try with the combination

```
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:applciation.properties") 
@ConfigurationProperties
```

to `TestConf.Java`

Comment: Be careful, you misspelt "application".

Answer (score 1):

So it seemed like the reason I did not get my value was not because of the code, but because the port was in use. I thought should not be an issue, but turned out that once I killed the process using the port and ran my application there, everything worked as expected. So my code was correct to begin with..

Thanks for your answers stackoverflow community

Answer (score 0):

Code needs couple of minor changes:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("classpath:application.properties")
public class TestConf {

  @Value("pres.firstName")
  private String firstName;
```

Comment: Won't fix the problems of not being a managed bean and of using unset fields from the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You have two fundamental problems:

1. Your `new TestConf()` instance isn't a Spring-managed object and thus doesn't get injected at all.
2. Setter (or field) injection inherently means that the values aren't set until after the constructor runs.

If you want to use a Spring bean from some task that gets run when you launch your Boot application, use a `CommandLineRunner` and inject the bean, preferably with constructor injection.

Answer (score 0):

> you can try with the combination..it will work....

```
@Component
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "pres")
@Data
public class TestConf {

  private String firstName;

.............

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Value to get a property's value or as you are trying to fetch the configs using a Configuration class, below example might be helpful.

A Controller class:

```
@RestController
public class ConfigurationController {

//@Value("${app.name:Movies}") 
//private String name;
//Alternative of configuration class

@Autowired
private Configuration configuration;

@GetMapping("/config")
public MovieConfiguration retrieveConfiguration() {

    return new MovieConfiguration(configuration.getName());
}
```

A Pojo class

```
public class MovieConfiguration {

private String name;

public MovieConfiguration(String name) {
    this.name=name;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}}
```

A Configuration class

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("app")
public class Configuration {

private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}}
```

Properties

```
server.port=8091
app.name=SpaceDrama
```